# Try to add Firebase analytics to Xamarin Android App

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-analytics

I try to add firebase analytics to my xamarain android app and whenn I add the nuget "Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics/121.3.0.2" I get the following error in the console when I start the App.

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
11-02 20:36:58.139 W/NetworkScheduler(11894):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)

When I remove this nuget then everything works fine and when I start the app there is no such error...

Does anyone knows a solultion for that? I couldn't found any solutions in the internet.

Comment: Probably has to do with this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/361#issuecomment-664593540 Maybe try installing an older version of FBA

Comment: You can try to use the previous version of the Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics. I use the previous version and it works well.